# input() vs sys.stdin.read()

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, python-3.2

```
import sys
s1 = input()
s2 = sys.stdin.read(1)

#type "s" for example

s1 == "s" #False
s2 == "s" #True
```

Why? How can I make `input()` to work properly?
I tried to encode/decode `s1`, but it doesn't work.

Thank you.

Comment: I guess you have you s1's and s2's mixed up in your last 2 lines?

Comment: Try to execute the code.

Comment: Works fine for me.  Are you're actually putting quotes around the s?  And what os/version of python are you using?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're on Windows, you'll notice that the result of `input()` when you type an 's' and Enter is `"s\r"`. Strip all trailing whitespace from the result and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 6):

You didn't say which version of Python you are using, so I'm going to guess you were using Python 3.2 running on Microsoft Windows.

This is a known bug see http://bugs.python.org/issue11272 "input() has trailing carriage return on windows"

Workarounds would include using a different version of Python, using an operating system that isn't windows, or stripping trailing carriage returns off any string() returned from `input()`. You should also be aware that iterating over stdin has the same problem.

Comment: Yes, it's version 3.2 on windows. Thank you for explanation. Problem solved.

Comment: On the 'use a different version of Python' suggestion, I see that Python 3.2.1rc1 has been released, so if you don't mind using a release candidate for a minor point fix you can just upgrade to that version and the issue is fixed. See http://www.python.org/download/releases/3.2.1/

Answer (score 0):

First, input is like [eval(raw_input())](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#input) which means that everything you pass to it will be evalualted as a python expresion. I suggest you to use raw_input() instead.

I tested your code and they're equal for me:

```
import sys
s1 = input()
s2 = sys.stdin.read(1)

if s1==s2 and s1=="s":
    print "They're both equal s"
```

This is the output:

```
flaper87@BigMac:/tmp$ python test.py 
"s"
s
They're both equal s
```

Using sys.stdin.read(1) will read just 1 character from the stdin which means that if you pass "s" just the first " will be read. There's sys.stdin.readline() which reads the whole line (including the final \n).

Comment: Note that when commenting on my answer @fogbit confirmed they are using Python 3.2 where `input()` is the correct thing to use. Your advice would only apply for earlier versions of Python.

Comment: You're right. When I posted my answer I didn't know the python version. I should've asked. Thanks ^^